# Why do we not have a closed form expression for counting transitivity?

Tags: co.combinatorics, closed-form-expressions

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation.

Are there any theoretical reasons out there which show us that why do we still not have a closed-form expression for transitivity counting. If you consider counting n-element binary relations of different types in the wiki article, then only transitivity seems to be missing(as partial order and preorder subsume transitivity). Are there any properties of transitivity that demonstrate the hardness of this problem.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/a/8980/ perhaps relevant?

Comment: It's not clear what problem you are referring to by "transitivity counting" or "counting transitivity".

Comment: It is referring to getting a closed-form expression to this series : https://oeis.org/A006905